# Сильно ли string ресурсозатратнее char[]?

Tags: c++

В интернете пишут только отличия string от char[], но не пишут, отличаются ли они по затратам и как сильно. Соответственно, вопрос: сильно ли string затратнее char[]?

Comment: не сильно. И вообще если С++ то char[] почти не используется.

Comment: Радикально отличается. `string` в общем случае занимается (пере) выделением динамической памяти для хранения массива символов.

Comment: Слегка ресурсозатратнее, но, имхо, удобство использования того стоит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В общем случае `std::string` медленее. Чтобы узнать насколько, надо делать замеры в вашем конкретном случае. Однако стоит отметить, что в большинстве реализаций для строк маленькой длины (<15?) применяется `short string optimization`, так что строка может хранится в стеке и быть потенциально не медленее `char[]`.